# Hyper-V on Windows 2019 Server or Windows 10 Pro Desktop for production use

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v, windows-server-2019, windows-10-pro

I want to virtualize my desktop PC, which is a) rather potent and b) always on anyway, and run some other VMs on that hardware. It is Windows 10 Pro right now.

The VMs will be production VMs, like Exchange, DPM, TFS (or Azure DevOPs) and similar.

I am wondering now whether to just enable Hyper-V on Windows 10 or whether to migrate the Windows 10 into a VM and run it inside a Windows Server 2019.

I am planning on using features like replication, snapshots, virtual switches. The harddrives will be Windows-software-mirrored either way.

I am planning to continue using the PC as my work PC, so if I install Windows Server, I would need to RDP into my current Desktop OS.

**Is there any advantage to using Windows Server 2019 over Windows 10 Pro for Hyper-V Virtualization?**

In case you wonder, it is a small shop, also, licensing and thus cost is not an issue.

Comment: Obviously there are advantages of one over the other, otherwise only one product would be offered. The real question is whether those differences are relevant to you; however this question isn't likely to be able to be asked in a way that doesn't run afoul of being too broad or opinion-based. Be sure to check the Help Center for advice on avoiding this.

Answer (score 1):

[According to Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/about/#differences-between-hyper-v-on-windows-and-hyper-v-on-windows-server):

There are some features that work differently in Hyper-V on Windows than they do in Hyper-V running on Windows Server.
Hyper-V features only available on Windows Server:

- Live migration of virtual machines from one host to another
- Hyper-V Replica
- Virtual Fiber Channel
- SR-IOV networking
- Shared .VHDX

Hyper-V features only available on Windows 10:

- Quick Create and the VM Gallery
- Default network (NAT switch)

The memory management model is different for Hyper-V on Windows. On a server, Hyper-V memory is managed with the assumption that only the virtual machines are running on the server. In Hyper-V on Windows, memory is managed with the expectation that most client machines are running software on host in addition to running virtual machines.

Comment: Many thanks, that means that mostly the Replica is relevant to me and missing there. Other features like SR-IOV I never managed to make work anyway, those have many requirements and even then could only be enabled via powershell.